# use inotify to watch a folder for a long time

Tags: monitoring

I want to use inotify to monitor a folder on my home folder for a long period time.Can inotify be used this way or do i need some kind of a server for this particular purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you need to know from monitoring it, but maybe

```
inotifywait -m -r ~/"The Folder"
```

is what you want?

Comment: Yes.I am uploading a file in the folder after very 30 minutes.Does inotify have some time limit for instance,can only run for 4 hours or does it run continually as long as the computer is running?.Do i need to start it,stop it,restart it,that kind of thing.

Comment: With the -m option, inotifywait will run indefinitely and print events as they happen. There's no time limit.